# Popup scroll not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

1. I am running my script in mozilla firefox  I want to scroll popup  I
   applied so many methods but doesn't work for me

   1. I used keys.tab to reach that element but it was unable to enter text in that textfield using `senkeys("xyz@gmail.com)`
   2. I used scroll method

      ```
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      js.executeScript("document.getElementById('youama-email').scrollIntoView(true);");
      ```

      some exception occur

   3.I used Moveto element method but got exception

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("youama-email"));
   ```

   Actions

   ```
    actions = new Actions(driver);     
    actions.moveToElement(element);    
    actions.click();       
    actions.perform();
   ```

   4. // Initialize Javascript executor

      ```
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      ```

   // Scroll inside web element vertically (e.g. 100 pixel)

   ```
       js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop =
        arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.id("<div-id>")), 100);
   ```

   Please help me to scroll and enter into the email as well as other
   fields that will appear after scroll [![enter image description
   here][1]][1]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0hqI.png

Comment: Just send me link of website where you want to perform that scrolling.

Comment: http://wyomingvapor.com/ this is the link and signup page

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think what you didn't do was to wait for the element to be visible which i did. See the below code. It is running correctly.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://wyomingvapor.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div/div[2]/div/a[1]")).click();


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='y-to-register']/input")));


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='y-to-register']/input")).click();


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='youama-firstname']")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='youama-firstname']")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000L);


    Robot robot  = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
```

If you still stuck then do reply to me, Jyotsana.
Happy Learning :-)

Comment: What is the error? I ran it on eclipse. For me it is working fine.

Comment: The code is for hitting on sign-in and then entering email address. It is not for sign-up process. Do you want for sign-up process?

Comment: Updated the code. Now try. Do reply if you still stuck :-)

Comment: ITs working for first name and last name but for email id during signup and as well as for password field are not working

Comment: Hi Jyotsana !! After long hard work. I found the solution, See the problem is not scroll. But when you find the xpath or any other locator there are many linked to same at below. I tried every technique to loacte it but it is not possible so the only option is by robot.
So please go ahead with robot method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113133/discussion-between-kishan-patel-and-jyotsana-namdev).